# Do short circuits between transformer windings cause noticeable change in EMF?

Tags: sensor, transformer, interference, emf

I am looking into developing a sensor system to be placed within a transformer. This sensor system in theory, should be able to detect any unprecedented change in EMF within the transformer enclosure.

I understand the EMF of a coil of wire is F= Turns*current in the windings.

In theory, a short within the windings would cause, a change in EMF, because the number of turns have changed.

**Is this the case?**

And would a small circuit being exposed to such high magnetic fields **potentially damage the circuit**. For the purposes of this question, let us assume the sensor is a small embedded system that is powered by a low-voltage DC battery.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and primarily what are you trying to measure?

Answer (score 1):

You need to describe much more clearly what you are doing - what do you mean by transformer enclosure?

A shorted turn in a transformer radically affects its operation far more than just reducing the voltage because of the reduced number of turns.

The shorted turn acts as a shorted secondary so it will pass a high current in a normal transformer and cause it to burn out.

If you are measuring the inductance or EMF of a winding of a transformer it will cause both to go very low, almost zero because any EMF generated will be counteracted by the current in the shorted turn.